# Artifacts in Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure devops pipeline that publishes output like this:

```
steps:
- script: ./something.sh
  displayName: build
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/app/build
  artifact: MyPackage
```

This works, and publishes a build artefact, but it's not available in the Artifacts page of Azure devops, and the only way to get to it is through an http url. Is there some way to publish the artefact to the Artifacts page? In addition, the url to the artefact has the buildid in it. Is there a way I can specify semver version numbers?

Comment: pipeline artifacts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml is not an Azure Artifacts: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/

Comment: as others have said, the 'Artifacts Page' is for azure artifacts which are mainly for maintaining nuget packages and all that. what you want, is to keep your 'BUILD artifacts' in a convenient place, perhaps. as the below answer suggest, you can get it in the pipelines page. if you want to keep all your build artifacts, then, you may want to setup up a blog storage or something, and then add a task to copy your build artifact to the blog storage and then access all of them in one place.

Comment: thanks guys... Azure Artifacts are indeed what's published in feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have your package available in Azure Artifacts you should publish it to feed. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you have an example with Universal Package.

Speaking about SemVer (from link above):

> In Universal Packages, a particular package is identified by its name and version number. Currently, Universal Packages require Semantic Versioning. Semantic version numbers have three numeric components, Major.Minor.Patch. When you fix a bug, you increment the patch (1.0.0 to 1.0.1). When you release a new backward-compatible feature, you increment the minor version and reset the patch version to 0 (1.4.17 to 1.5.0). When you make a backward-incompatible change, you increment the major version and reset the minor and patch versions to 0 (2.6.5 to 3.0.0).
>
> The Universal Packages task automatically selects the next major, minor, or patch version for you when you publish a new package. Just set the appropriate option.

And you build/pipeline artifact you will find here:
[image]